# Is there a gud-like octave debugging mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, octave

I know there are commands like *dbstop* and *dbstep* etc. to debug a **Octave** scripts. I want to find a mode like **gud** in Emacs for Octave but failed. Is there one mode like this? Or how can I implement one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no GUD-like for Octave. Besides, the Emacs mode for Octave is obsolete. There is a dev branch in Octave which aims to create a GUI for Octave based on Qt. I have no idea when the GUI will be mature enough. R has a very quite GUI frontend R-studio. I just hope Octave community will have the similar nice counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an emacs user myself, but according to this thread:
[How to use octave in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961007/how-to-use-octave-in-vscode)
you can run the octave debugger in VS code. I just tried it and it's amazing. This is huge for octave users, as the Octave GUI debugger is critically flawed by an occasional inability to retain breakpoints after the file is edited/saved. This bug has been around for years, but just the other day as I started a new project in Octave 5.2.0, a new behaviour of the bug cropped up which I'd never seen before making it even more frustrating. This news about VS code came just at the right time for me.